# global service not working in angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-services

I have created one global service in angular2 for accessing variables across all components like below.

**global.objects.service.ts**

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

export class GlobalObjectsService {
  workspace:any;     
  constructor() {    
  }  
}
```

Then I am able to access & set new value to this object in my `workspace.component` like below:

```
import {Component, OnInit,Input} from 'angular2/core';
import { GlobalService} from './../../../app/shared/services/global/global.service';
import { GlobalObjectsService} from './../../shared/services/global/global.objects.service';
import { WorkspaceService } from './../../../app/shared/services/pm/workspaces.service';   

@Component({
    selector: 'workspaces',
    providers:[WorkspaceService],        
    templateUrl: 'app/project-manager/workspaces/workspaces.component.html'
})

export class WorkspacesComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() workspaces:any;    
    constructor(private globalService:GlobalService,private globalObjectsService:GlobalObjectsService,private workspaceService:WorkspaceService) { }

    ngOnInit() { }    
    selectWorkspace(workspace_id:string){
       this.workspaceService.getWorkspaceById(workspace_id,this.globalService.baseUrl).subscribe((workspace)=>{
           this.globalObjectsService.workspace=workspace; 
           console.log(this.globalObjectsService.workspace);  //this prints workspace correctly        
       });           
    }    
}
```

But when I am trying to access this global Object in below component its showing `undefined`

```
import {Component, OnInit ,Input} from 'angular2/core';
import { GlobalObjectsService} from './../../shared/services/global/global.objects.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'pages',    
    templateUrl: 'app/project-manager/pages/pages.component.html'
})
export class PagesComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() pages:any;
    public workspace:any;    
    constructor(private globalObjectsService:GlobalObjectsService) {
        this.workspace=this.globalObjectsService.workspace; 
        console.log(this.workspace);  //this is not working           
    }
    ngOnInit() { }        
}
```

I have not included `global.objects.service` in `providers` of any component except the root component while bootstrapping.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service is missing the `@Injectable()` directive. Just add it like this:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalObjectsService {
  workspace:any;     
  constructor() {    
  }  
}
```

Read more on dependency injection in Angular 2 [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html).

Comment: My bad :p thnx for the help

Comment: It's good practice according to the style guide to add `@Injectable()` but if the constructor doesn't have any parameters, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are missing is to inject a `WorkspaceService` into `GlobalObjectsService`

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalObjectsService {
  constructor(public workspace:WorkspaceService) {    
  }  
}
```

You need to provide `WorkspaceService` like `GlobalObjectsService`. A global `GlobalObjectsService` can't have a more local `WorkspaceService` injected depending on where you inject `GlobalObjectsService`